# Undefined references for aruco::MarkerDetector

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, aruco

I'm trying to get the marker position in an image, but when I compile the program, during linking, I receive several errors indicating undefined reference to Aruco (`Marker.cpp:(.text+0x1643): undefined reference to 'aruco::MarkerDetector::detect(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<aruco::Marker, std::allocator<aruco::Marker> >&, cv::Mat, cv::Mat, float, bool)'`), I've looked for solutions regarding linking the library but none of them seem to work. This is my CMakeList.txt:

```
# cmake needs this line
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Define project name
project(Pruebas_alg_new)

# Find OpenCV, you may need to set OpenCV_DIR variable
# to the absolute path to the directory containing OpenCVConfig.cmake file
# via the command line or GUI
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(aruco)

# If the package has been found, several variables will
# be set, you can find the full list with descriptions
# in the OpenCVConfig.cmake file.
# Print some message showing some of them
message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    config: ${OpenCV_DIR}")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(Marker Marker.cpp) 

target_link_libraries(Marker PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

And here is the code I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include "Euler.hpp"
#include <aruco/aruco.h>
#include <aruco/markerdetector.h>
#include <aruco/marker.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{


    Mat img_scene = imread("/home/javier/pruebas/MasPruebas/Imagenes/Scene.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );

     if( /*!img_object.data ||*/ !img_scene.data )
     { std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl;}

     Mat CameraMatrix = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << 374.67,0,320.5,0,374.67,180.5,0,0,1);

    aruco::MarkerDetector MDetector;
        vector<aruco::Marker> Markers;

     //DetectorParameters::create()

        MDetector.detect(img_scene,Markers);
     std::cout<< Markers.size() << std::endl;
    // if at least one marker detected
         for (unsigned int i = 0; i<Markers.size(); i++)
            {Markers[i].draw(img_scene,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);}
         cv::imshow("out", img_scene);


    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you try adding `link_directories(${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS})` to the cmake file?

Comment: The linking returns the same error. :(

Comment: I do not have access to a computer with OpenCV installed right now, and I do not if this makes a difference, but can you try changing linking to `target_link_libraries(Marker PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})`? Also, did you build the aruco library when you built OpenCV?